# Splitting Screen in Areas to controll object

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

im kinda stuck with this problem.
The idea is to have the blue square (player2) move when the top half of the screen is touched and the red square (player1) when the bottom half is touched.

I tried to make rect for the top and and bottom half and telling for example the red one to only move when the touch is within the bottom rect.

[image: Screenshot]

But the current behavior is like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyVzuXFXipM

Player1 Script: https://www.codepile.net/pile/jAN8RgMl 
Player2 Script: https://www.codepile.net/pile/6dxO7lX3

The coords i determined i would need:[image: coords]
coords in the middle might be inaccurate but the corners should be correct.

Comment: Please post your code here and not in some external link.

Answer (score 0):

In general please post your code here and not in some external link!

---

At first glance: Be aware that you would have to provide the texts in **screen pixel coordinates**!

You are once starting at `y = 0` and once at `y = 5` ..  that's just 5 pixels from the bottom!

You probably would rather want to use

```c#
var bottomRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height / 2f);
```

and

```c#
var topRect = new Rect(0, Screen.height / 2f, Screen.width, Screen.height / 2f);
```

---

Btw If this is the only difference between your scripts you shouldn't use two different scripts but rather use the same script and only use different `Rect`s like e.g.

```c#
public enum Player
{
    Top,
    Bottom
}

// Adjust this via the Inspector
public Player player;
```

and then

```c#
private Rect rect;

private void Awake ()
{
    rect = player == Player.Top ? new Rect(0, Screen.height / 2f, Screen.width, Screen.height / 2f) : new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height / 2f);
}
```